# Calling multi-level commands/programs from python

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell command 'fst-mor'. It takes an argument in form of file e.g. NOUN.A which is a lex file or something. Final command : `fst-mor NOUN.A`

It then produces following output:

```
analyze>INPUT_A_STRING_HERE
OUTPUT_HERE
```

Now I want to put call that fst-mor from my python script and then input string and want back output in the script.

So far I have:

```
import os
print os.system("fst-mor NOUN.A")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to capture the output of another command. Use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for this.

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output('fst-mor', 'NOUN.A')
```

If your command requires interactive input, you have two options:

- Use a `subprocess.Popen()` object, and set the `stdin` parameter to `subprocess.PIPE` and write the input to the stdin pipe available. For one input parameter, that's often enough. Study the documentation for the `subprocess` module for details, but the basic interaction is:

  ```
  proc = subprocess.Popen(['fst-mor', 'NOUN.A'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  output, err = proc.communicate('INPUT_A_STRING_HERE')
  ```
- Use the [`pexpect` library](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to drive a process. This let's you create more complex interactions with a subprocess by looking for patterns is the output it generates:

  ```
  import pexpect

  py = pexpect.spawn('fst-mor NOUN.A')
  py.expect('analyze>')
  py.send('INPUT_A_STRING_HERE')
  output = py.read()
  py.close()
  ```

Comment: It's again asking me to input that INPUT_STRING. I don't want to input on terminal. I want to have that INPUT_STRING taken from script as well and returned that OUTPUT_STRING to the script

Comment: @AkshatGoel: expanded the answer a little. If you can give the `fst-mor` command more command-line parameters instead it might be easier though.

Comment: Thanks man! But the edited answer is not helping either. Can you please post elaborated code if you have time now or maybe a bit later? I may phrase the problem in easier terms like this. You are calling a typical program of codechef or spoj from this script and you also want to input those 'test', 'input' variables of the program from the script and retrieve the result in the script.

Comment: @AkshatGoel: I understand what you are trying to do. The options you have don't change. I'll see what I can do to expand that a little.

Comment: Thanks! I will really appreciate that. This is a research based academic project and we have reached nowhere so far since we are stuck on this problem since ever now! :(

Comment: Thank you sir! :) You saved my day (night in this part of the world) ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["fst-mor", "NOUN.A"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate("INPUT_A_STRING_HERE")[0]
```

Comment: Thanks man! I have upvoted the answer but to be fair, I will have to accept Martijn's answer! :) Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 0):

A sample that communicates with another process:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(['clisp'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(response,err) = pipe.communicate("(+ 1 1)\n(* 2 2)")
#only print the last 6 lines to chop off the REPL intro text. 
#Obviously you can do whatever manipulations you feel are necessary 
#to correctly grab the input here
print '\n'.join(response.split('\n')[-6:])
```

Note that communicate will close the streams after it runs, so you have to know all your commands ahead of time for this method to work. It seems like the pipe.stdout doesn't flush until stdin is closed? I'd be curious if there is a way around that I'm missing.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the subprocess module [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

In your example you might run:

```
subprocess.check_output(["fst-mor", "NOUN.A"])
```